# HTML/JS - Block one button by another button and reset it by another button

Tags: javascript, html, button

```
<body>
<script>
MQTTconnect();

var clicked_f = 0;
var clicked_b = 0;

if (clicked_f > 0) {
    document.getElementById("backw_button").disabled = true;
    alert("BACKWARD button is disabled.");
}
if (clicked_b > 0) {
    document.getElementById("fwr_button").disabled = true;
    alert("FORWARD button is disabled.");
}
if (document.getElementById("stop_b").clicked == true) {
    clicked_f = 0;
    clicked_b = 0;
}
else{
    document.getElementById("backw_button").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("fwr_button").disabled = false;
}

function c_for() 
{
    message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("1");
    message.destinationName = "train/direction";
    mqtt.send(message);
}
function forw() 
{   
    mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,port,"clientjs");
    var options = {
        timeout: 3,
        onSuccess: c_for,
        };   
    mqtt.connect(options);
}

function c_back() 
{
    message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("2");
    message.destinationName = "train/direction";
    mqtt.send(message);
}
function forw() 
{
    mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,port,"clientjs");
    var options = {
        timeout: 3,
        onSuccess: c_for,
        };   
    mqtt.connect(options);
}

function MQTTconnect() 
{
console.log("connecting to "+ host +" "+ port);
mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,port,"clientjs");
var options = {
    timeout: 3,
    onSuccess: onConnect,
    };
     
mqtt.connect(options);
}

</script>

<div class="inputik" style="width: 290px;padding: 20px ">
        <h3>Direction:</h3>
        <button id="fwr_button" onclick="clicked_f++;forw();" style="background-color: #009600">FORWARD</button>
        <button id="stop_b" onclick="vyp()" style="background-color: #990000">STOP</button>
        <button id="backw_button" onclick="clicked_b++;backw();" style="background-color: #2247ff">BACKWARD</button>
</div><br>
```

> You cant press FORWARD button and BACKWARD in order, you must press STOP button between them. I just need disable one button by another button and vice versa and by STOP button enable both of them. MQTT doesnt matter i just need to disable one button at the time to not send messages. I just dont know where the mistake is

Comment: I don't see your `MQTTconnect()` and any `onclick` function. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Yes I did, I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

You're never updating the `disabled`-state of the buttons after the first load. You're only updating the `clicked_f` and `clicked_b` fields, but this won't cause the script to be re-executed.

I believe your problem will become a lot more simple if you just keep track of the `position` you're navigating towards or away from. And if you update the disabled state of your buttons using this `position`.

Like this:

```js
let position = 0;

function forwardButtonClicked() {
  // Note: call your MQTT function here
  position++;
  updateButtons();
}

function stopButtonClicked() {
  position = 0;
  updateButtons();
}

function backwardButtonClicked() {
  // Note: call your MQTT function here
  position--;
  updateButtons();
}

function updateButtons() {
  console.log(position); // Only here for demonstration
  document.getElementById("backward_button").disabled = position > 0;
  document.getElementById("forward_button").disabled = position < 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="forward_button" onclick="forwardButtonClicked()">FORWARD</button>
<button onclick="stopButtonClicked()">STOP</button>
<button id="backward_button" onclick="backwardButtonClicked()">BACKWARD</button>
```